# How increase mysql query if include query " . - / ' etc

Tags: mysql, performance

How can i improve mysql query if include point, comma etc.. 
My data size is 3GB and 12,000,000 row.

My System Information

Time of this report: 4/20/2018, 13:55:16
       Operating System: Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard 64-bit (6.1, Build 7600) (7600.win7_gdr.120401-1505)
               Language: Turkish (Regional Setting: Turkish)
    System Manufacturer: VMware, Inc.
           System Model: VMware Virtual Platform
                   BIOS: PhoenixBIOS 4.0 Release 6.0
              Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1245 V2 @ 3.40GHz (8 CPUs), ~3.4GHz
                 Memory: 16384MB RAM
    Available OS Memory: 16384MB RAM
              Page File: 8402MB used, 24362MB available
            Windows Dir: C:\Windows
        DirectX Version: DirectX 11
    DX Setup Parameters: Not found
       User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
     System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
        DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
         DxDiag Version: 6.01.7600.16385 32bit Unicode

MY.ini file is:

```
[client]
port=3306

[mysql]
no-beep=
[mysqld]
port=3306
datadir=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Data
default-storage-engine=INNODB
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
log-output=FILE
general-log=0
general_log_file="WIN-FFJIGKKSAPK.log"
slow-query-log=1
slow_query_log_file="WIN-FFJIGKKSAPK-slow.log"
long_query_time=10
log-error="WIN-FFJIGKKSAPK.err"
server-id=1
secure-file-priv="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads"



max_connections = 2000
query_cache_size = 0
table_open_cache=39390
open_files_limit=78780   
tmp_table_size = 20M
thread_cache_size = 100
myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
key_buffer_size = 32M
read_buffer_size=64K
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 6000M
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
innodb_thread_concurrency=0
innodb_autoextend_increment=64
innodb_write_io_threads = 16
innodb_read_io_threads = 16
innodb_io_capacity=500
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8


innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000
innodb_old_blocks_time=1000
innodb_open_files=300
innodb_stats_on_metadata=0
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_checksum_algorithm=0
back_log=80
flush_time=0
join_buffer_size=256K
max_allowed_packet = 16M
query_cache_type=0
sort_buffer_size=256K
table_definition_cache=1400
binlog_row_event_max_size=8K
sync_master_info=10000
sync_relay_log=10000
sync_relay_log_info=10000
ft_min_word_len = 3
max_connect_errors = 1000000
expire_logs_days = 14
max_heap_table_size = 32M
myisam-recover-options = FORCE
slave-net-timeout = 60
sync_binlog = 1
skip-name-resolve
```

please help me i want to speed up mysql queries. thank you

Comment: What does **include point, comma etc..** mean?

Comment: for example when i use stackoverflow com its normal but if include . it is so much time "stackoverflow.com" etc.

Comment: I still have no idea what you mean by that. There's nothing special about comma and point in SQL.

Comment: If you're having problems with a specific query, you need to post it. And for performance issues, post the output of `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: You may just need to add appropriate indexes.

Comment: If you look at the config file, you see that there is any problem or need editing or missing space?

Comment: Post the SQL query also.

Comment: I have no idea. If you want help in configuring the database, [dba.se] is the place to ask.

Comment: Are you talking about `FULLTEXT`??